# Getting 404 not found error in google app engine with python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, windows-7-x64, google-app-engine-python

When I want to upload my python app to online, I am getting 404 not found error. Though on localhost app works perfectly. The reason was in user folder name, it was written with Russian letters (Windows 7). The error is:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (UnicodeEncodeError): 'ascii' codec can't encode character
s in position 9-14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So, how can I upload my app online?

Comment: Unicode can be tough to debug when you are new to it.  I suggest changing to ascii folder names to get it working.  Once you have it working, you can switch back to Russian if you like.